# Не работает помещение шаблона в script type=text/ng-template

Tags: angularjs

В следующем примере я ожидаю, что разметка для view возьмётся из

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="main-page">
```

однако вместо этого отправляется http-запрос на сервер:

[image: скриншот]

Что я делаю не так?

```js
angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'main-page'
    })
    .otherwise({
      template: '<h1>404</h1>'
    })
})
```

```html
<script  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<main ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-view>Turn on javascript!</div>
</main> 
  
<script type="text/ng-template" id="main-page">
  <h1>It works!</h1>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт с типом `text/ng-template` должен находиться внутри `ng-app`, поскольку он является директивой, помещающей разметку в кэш шаблонов.

```js
angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'main-page'
    })
    .otherwise({
      template: '<h1>404</h1>'
    })
})
```

```html
<script  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<main ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-view>Turn on javascript!</div>
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="main-page">
    <h1>It works!</h1>
  </script>
</main>
```